# Bootstrap 5 Dropdown Menu Not Dropping Down

Tags: javascript, php, css, bootstrap-5

Trying to get a dropdown menu to work on Wordpress using Bootstrap. However its not dropping down. If i manually add the class show to my dropdown-menu div the menu shows, the button just dosent work.

Scripts being called:

```
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Dropdown Code:

```
    <li id="menu-item-9365" class="has-mega-menu menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown nav-item nav-item-9365" has-megamenu="">
<a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdownMenuLink" role="button">Shop</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu megamenu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-12">
                           DROPDOWN MENU ITEMS HERE
                        </div><!-- end col-4 -->
                           
                        
                    </div><!-- end row --> 
                </div> <!-- dropdown-mega-menu.// -->
</li>
```

Comment: For me it drops, on click. https://jsfiddle.net/itgoldman/up6qw5ot/3/

Comment: Hmm. Thats odd. Any idea how to work out whats conflicting with it?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with Bootsraop 5.
The solution is to use [WP Bootstrap Navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker#usage-with-bootstrap-5)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).